# Issues with my Android custom sprite Class

Tags: java, android, sprite

I am currently designing a basic sprite class for java for android because for I don't wish to use a 2d engine and Google doesn't provide any sprite APIs for some reason...

Anyways, my question is in regards to my Classes I have designed. I have a Sprite Class that takes a bitmap and turns it into a "sprite". This sprite can then be passed to a custom view I have created when the user creates a new "SpriteContainer"

My code for the DynamicSpriteContainer is as follows:

```
package com.me.spriteGraphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class DynamicSpriteContainer extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    public int x, y;
    private Bitmap b;
    public Sprite sprite;
    private Canvas c = new Canvas();
    private boolean bool = false;

    public DynamicSpriteContainer(Context context, Sprite spriteImage) {
        //public ImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //get sprite
        b = spriteImage.getBitmap();

        //set holder
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);

        //set position
        x = y = 0;

        update();
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);

        //set up bitmap image
        c.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        update();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    private void update() {
        //this code will alter the character in the way the developer specifies (per frame)
        Thread repeat = new Thread( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //move sprite in constant motion
                    while (bool) {
                        //redraw
                        c = holder.lockCanvas();
                        c.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);

                        //set up bitmap image
                        c.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                } catch (Error e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    bool = false;
                }
            }
        });
        repeat.start();
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        //notice how this same code above has the holder, the holder is recognized above, not here.
        c = holder.lockCanvas();
        c.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);

        //set up bitmap image
        c.drawBitmap(b, x, y, null);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);       
    }

    //set the info on pause, resume, stop...
    //this data is for error stopping, so the app can resume and stop without passing an error to the user!
    public void passInfo(boolean isPaused, boolean isResumed, boolean isStopped) {
        if (isPaused && sprite.auto) {
            bool = false;
        }

        if (isResumed && sprite.auto) {
            bool = true;
        }

        if (isStopped && sprite.auto) {
            bool = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long code excerpt.

The main issue is that inside the update() function, the holder is recognized, but inside the setX(), it's not...

How can I have the setX() recognize the holder?

Thank you soo much in advance!!!

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Your IDE is not resolving `holder`?

Comment: It gives a nullPointerExeption on the holder only there in setX

Comment: The `lockCanvas()` method returns null if the canvas wasn't unlocked. It is possible that the canvas is in use by the `update()` method when you're calling `setX()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have tried using setX with the update function commented out. It still gives the same response